Make .dir-locals works with compilation
I'm using Emacs 29.1 I have the following .dir-locals.el file:
((nil . ((compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist . '(acap "^#[0-9]+ [0-9]\.[0-9]+ \\(.+?\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\).*" 1 2 3))
         (compilation-error-regexp-alist . '(acap))
         (compilation-scroll-output . 'first-error)
         (compile-command . "./Build.sh"))))


But, it does not work (when calling M-x compile the command & variables are not set) and apparently it's for several reasons.
First, these variable don't seem to be buffer local. But even if I make-variable-buffer-local some of them it seems to only work for compile-command (that is, these variables are set in the source buffer but when calling M-x compile then only compile-command is set but for example compilation-scroll-output is not.
Then, it seems M-x compile does not care about theses variable until I use (setq compilation-process-setup-function #'hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer), I guess it's because the compilation buffer is not a file and thus .dir-locals.el is ignored.
Should I just give up on dir locals variable?
I just want to have a custom error parsing on this projet the simplest way possible.

There's no need to quote.  Write (acap) instead of '(acap).

Thanks, but it does not fix my issue tho

Yes, dir-locals will not work for this. You can define your own my/compile command which uses let to redefine the variables temporarily before calling the standard compile command.

@NickD: Consider posting your comment as an answer. Thx.

Thanks, yes @NickD post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Bonus point if you clarify why it does not work, buffer-local variables confuse me a lot.

I think there is more here than meets the eye: some variables (compile-command e.g.) can be specified through file-or-dir-locals and affect the compile command; the rest are things that affect the *Compilation* buffer only and the functions that you use to e.g. navigate through errors (next-error and friends). So two different mechanisms are needed. However I have not had time to think about this any more and check to make sure that I'm talking sense.
